# What is the default color space in PIL?

Tags: python, rgb, color-space

What is the color space when importing an image with PIL if the mode is RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true color)? CIE RGB with Reference White E?

Comment: Unless a colour profile is included or you know otherwise from some external source, you could generally assume an image is in `sRGB` colourspace.

Answer (score 1):

your question is ambiguous, but as far as I understand you it's up to the image to define what color space it lives in.  you'd need to use a ["color management system"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management) if you care much about calibration/reference colors

the RGB tuples in PIL are just the (raw) values encoded in the file, but Pillow exposes the [`ImageCms`  module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageCms.html) for when you care about getting correct values

the last time I looked into it (a few years ago) very few places actually cared about this so images didn't contain useful CMS information or when they do it was often wrong (e.g. just the default value from the program they used to create the image)

Comment: Ok, but if I want to convert an image from RGB to XYZ without PIL I need to convert the image in specific color space?

Comment: what do you mean by "color space"?  e.g. do you care about ICC profiles, or do you just want the RGB pixels converted to "XYZ color space" and you're happy to ignore the details

Answer (score 1):

if the image hasn't a icc profile associated with it, it's a sRGB image in most cases.

from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB

> sRGB is an RGB (red, green, blue) color space that HP and Microsoft
> created cooperatively in 1996 to use on monitors, printers, and the
> Web. It was subsequently standardized by the IEC as IEC
> 61966-2-1:1999.[1] It is often the "default" color space for images
> that contain no color space information, especially if the images'
> pixels are stored in 8-bit integers per color channel.